# Map controllers under a different context than actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, contextpath

I would like to map all my controllers under a context path called `/network`, but my Actuator path under `/actuator`. I've attempted the following configuration in my `application.properties`, but the actuator path becomes `/network/actuator`, instead of `/actuator`:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/network
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
```

I've tried using the (deprecated) `management.server.servlet.context-path` property too, but this resulted in the same issue.

As a workaround, I can annotate my controllers with `@RequestMapping`, but it would be great if I can use the context path instead. I'm using `Spring Boot 3.0.6.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use such approach with separate configuration for this purpose:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerTypePredicate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class BasePathConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("network", HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage("com.example.controllers"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, this might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. From the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.monitoring.customizing-management-server-context-path):

> Unless the management port has been configured to expose endpoints by using a different HTTP port, `management.endpoints.web.base-path` is relative to `server.servlet.context-path` (for servlet web applications) or `spring.webflux.base-path` (for reactive web applications). If `management.server.port` is configured, `management.endpoints.web.base-path` is relative to `management.server.base-path`.

So your options are to set `management.server.port` to a value that is different from `server.port` to get separate base paths, or change your application endpoint mappings as you suggested.

Comment: I am not sure setting a different port will fix it, I don't think the `management.server.base-path` is `/`, but equal to the context path instead? Maybe I'm reading this wrong though. Either way, I can't change the port, that would be too complex within our infra.